# Why is my harddisk not displaying after fsck command recovery of superblock?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

My laptop is working on a triple booted machine with ubuntu ,parrot os and windows 10. In the morning,I boot into ubuntu and bad blocks error poppped up.Thus I ran up the recovery of ubuntu and it was working fine until I ran the commands

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I thought they might solve the problems but rather they increased the errors
I started getting errors like 
Problem unlinking the filesystem /var/cache...(READ-only filesytem)
So I booted my live usb and ran fsck commands

```
dumpe2fs /dev/sda15 | grep superblock
```

since my ubuntu was on sda15 
I got a pretty good list of bad superblocks
which I tried to end with rewriting the block

```
fsck -b 32768 /dev/sda15
```

I again tried to mount the sda15 partition
and got "cant find superblock" error
Again i ran the command

```
blkid
```

And I get the result as

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="UUI" UUID="1502-3F40" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="3eb55fec-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
```

Suddenly My 1TB harddisk has disappeared.
I also ran the testdisk

```
sudo testdisk /list

 TestDisk 7.0, Data Recovery Utility, April 2015
 Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
 http://www.cgsecurity.org
 Please wait...
 Disk /dev/sda - 15 GB / 14 GiB - CHS 15216 64 32
 Sector size:512
 Model: SRT USB, FW:1100

 Disk /dev/sda - 15 GB / 14 GiB - CHS 15216 64 32
     Partition          Start        End    Size in sectors
 1 * FAT32 LBA                1   0  1 15215  63 32   31160320 [UUI]
     FAT32, blocksize=8192
```

I also ran few other commands to list my harddisk but it is not even displaying.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l |grep dev
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1497772032 bytes, 2925336 sectors
Disk /dev/sda: 14.9 GiB, 15955132416 bytes, 31162368 sectors
/dev/sda1  *     2048 31162367 31160320 14.9G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

My boot mbr is stored in /dev/sda
and my current /dev/sda1 is loaded as my live usb 
Can my harddisk be recovered!!!
I am pretty sure that my NTFS harddisk is not corrupted!!

Comment: Before anything else check BIOS/UEFI. Is the HDD still recognized there? If yes, proceed with troubleshooting; if not your HDD is dead and not surprising because it was failing already.